# How to know PDF is readOnly or not using IText

Tags: pdf, itext

I want to place watermark stamps on all PDFs which I currently have, but some are read-only. Is there any way I can know whether a file that I've opened is read-only or is not editable using **IText**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways - one might just be file permissions (you did check those, right?) the other way is to see if there is an encryption object and no user password (in other words, the document is encrypted with no user password, but with an owner password).  In this case the encryption dictionary will have a member called `/P` which is a bitfield of flags of allowable operations.  Table 22 of the ISO PDF spec describes the meaning.  Likely the 4th bit (1 << 3) is cleared, which means no modifications.

Comment: But issue is not with File persmissions.. the PDF itself configured has readonly files.. not allowed for modification i want to check programmatically using IText

Comment: You misunderstood the answer. If a PDF itself is configured as read-only, it means that somebody encrypted the file and defined specific *permissions*. Somehow you assume that these permissions are file permissions on the OS level. This assumption is wrong. The answer is correct (hence my up-vote): check if the PDF is encrypted and if so, check its permissions.